# debug vs release build?? xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

Is there any difference between the debug and release build in terms of code / dependancies?

I recently started using test flight (this uses release builds) and have had nothing but crashes. It works perfectly when I build for debug.

Anyone had this problem?

At the moment I get a exc_breakpoint when the app hits "return true"
Which seems very weird. There is nothing to go wrong when all you have to do is return "true"

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


func calculateRelevance (album: AlbumLight , currentLocation: CLLocation, currentCity: String) -> Bool {

    let fromLocationLa: CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(album.la!)
    let fromLocationLo: CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(album.lo!)

    var fromLocation: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: fromLocationLa, longitude: fromLocationLo)
    let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(currentLocation)

    if album.isActive == true {
        if album.hasRange == true {
            if distance < Double(album.range!) {

                return true

           }
            else {

                return false

            }
        }
        else {
            if currentCity == album.city {

                return true

            }
            else {

                return false

            }
        }
    }
    else {

        return false

    }
}
```

---

Update :

After a lot of trial and error, I found that adding a println() to get certain values prevents my bugs. For some reason something that isn't nil is turned into nil except for when I call println() just before using the value. Makes no sense to me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guess, I think the optimizer is biting you. `fromLocationLa`, `fromLocationLo`, `fromLocation`, and `distance` are only used once. This means the following optimization can be done.

```
…
let fromLocationLa: CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(album.la!)
let fromLocationLo: CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(album.lo!)

var fromLocation: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: fromLocationLa, longitude: fromLocationLo)
let distance = fromLocation.distanceFromLocation(currentLocation)

if album.isActive == true {
    if album.hasRange == true {
        if distance < Double(album.range!) {

            return true

        }
        else {

            return false

        }
    }
…
```

optimized to

```
if album.isActive == true {
    if album.hasRange == true {
        return CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(album.la!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(album.lo!)).distanceFromLocation(currentLocation) < Double(album.range!)
    }
```

This could explain the odd line number in the optimized code. It also put lots of implicit unwrapping on a single line.

Given the problems you seem to be having, a bit more care might be needed when unwrapping optionals.

```
let fromLocationLa: CLLocationDegrees? = album.la != nil ? CLLocationDegrees(album.la!) : nil
let fromLocationLo: CLLocationDegrees? = album.la != nil ? CLLocationDegrees(album.lo!) : nil

var fromLocation: CLLocation? = fromLocationLa != nil && fromLocationLo != nil ? CLLocation(latitude: fromLocationLa!, longitude: fromLocationLo!) : nil
let distance = fromLocation?.distanceFromLocation(currentLocation)

if album.isActive == true {
    if album.hasRange == true {
        if distance != nil && album.range != nil && distance! < Double(album.range!) {

            return true

        }
        else {

            return false

        }
    }
```

Comment: That is all true :) But why is the release build giving problems where the debug isn't? and why is println() on the line before the real call a fix. It only calls a value in the same way that any other call does, or not? Anyway. I fixed it, by doing exactly what you suggested. I optimised it and moved some stuff from a separate function back into the main function. Moving optionals around too much causes problems apparently. Good to know that I was on the right track. Understanding the real issue is overrated anyway

Comment: also I removed every println() from my code, just too make sure I am not fixing any other bugs in the same way. Found a couple more. Really weird...

Comment: Tracking down the exact problem could be very difficult. Tracking down the exact optimization (or combinations of optimizations) which caused your failure could be very difficult.

Comment: posting +10.000 lines of code on SO to let other people find my bug is also a bit rude ;)